# What is the default login password for Oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle, passwords, default

I just installed Oracle 12C on my home machine and didn't remember it asking to create any credentials during installation. Now, when I'm trying to connect to sample ORCL database, it's prompting one and not letting me in without!

Answer (score 2):

Log on to the Oracle DB server machine as a user who installed it, so that you can access the db as SYS using:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

When you get connected, you will be able to reset password for all the other users, including SYSTEM and the other “built-in” users as bellow:

`ALTER USER user_name IDENTIFIED BY new_password;`

Comment: Hello! If the answer helped, you may mark it as accepted as it helps other readers too. Otherwise please comment the issue you are facing so we can help with it.

Comment: I installed it Windows 10, so where do i get to use the above sysdba command?

Comment: On Windows: Click Start, point to Programs (or All Programs), point to Oracle Database 10g Express (whatever) Edition, and then select Run SQL Command Line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just realized the user name is 'system' and was able to login!